# Не удается вызвать проект в Blazor ASP Net Core из браузера

Tags: asp.net-core

Создан типовой шаблон проекта Blazor в ASP Net Core в VS 2019. 
Тестовый проект запускается, все нормально работает.
При попытке вызвать этот проект по адресу из браузера вылетает ошибка:
"InvalidOperationException: 'Router' cannot find any component with a route for '/Index', and no fallback is defined".
Никто не сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена переустановкой SDK.